# Please render mathematics in edit diffs

Tags: feature-request, mathjax

Edit diffs do not render mathematical formatting. For example, here's a view from a suggested edit review:

[image: suggested edit review screenshot]

This makes it difficult to understand what the mathematical parts of the new versions are.

Please render MathJax in edit diffs. If it's really too difficult to combine the red/green coloring with MathJax, at least provide a separate side-by-side view with MathJax rendering but no coloring.

<sub>[Similar feature request on the main meta](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/200496/latex-rendering-for-suggested-edit-queue)</sub>

Comment: The issue might be that it might hide some changes from the viewer.

Comment: @Kaveh I'd prefer to have the whole equation in green than seeing the source like this, and that's coming from someone who can read TeX math fluently, at least when it's indented properly (which it isn't here).

Comment: I have up voted the request, I just wanted to point out why it might be problematic: one can write stuff inside $ signs and hide it from the view so the review will not be a complete review of the changes. ps: One thing you can do is use the user script they use on [math.se] chat to render math.

Comment: This seems to be implemented in the revision history (see e.g. [here](http://cs.stackexchange.com/posts/13981/revisions)); does the suggested edit view differ (don't have one at hand)?

Comment: @Kaveh Good point, although I imagine that only few posts use "hidden" LaTeX. Note, though, that you can always inspect the LaTeX source by right-clicking on rendered math.

Comment: @Raphael Really? You don't see any `$` in the diff for revision 2? It's only if the whole equation is changed that it gets rendered for me.

Comment: @Gilles Ah, so it affects only (partially) changed formulae. Got it.